# SQL SELECT statements - different number of columns

Tags: sql

What's wrong with this query?

```
sql error: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

```
SELECT `id`,`firstname`,`lastname` FROM `users` WHERE `firstname` LIKE 
'%ned%' OR `lastname` LIKE '%ned%' 
OR CONCAT(`firstname`," ", `lastname`) LIKE '%ned%' 
OR CONCAT(`lastname`," ", `firstname`) LIKE '%ned%' 
UNION SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `friends` ON `users`.`id`=`friends`.`user_id`
```

Users table

```
+------------------------------------------+
|   id   |  firstname | lastname | ....    |
|   1    |   Nedim    |  Kanat   |  ....   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Friends table

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|   id   |  user_id   | friend_id | ....    |
|   1    |   1        |  2        |  ....   |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't know. What is the problem?

Comment: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @IdontReallywolf The second select statement has only one column.

Comment: Well, yeah. That's not allowed when you use `UNION`, which combines two result sets with the same number of columns into one. What's the result you're looking for?

Comment: @jeroen-mostert Im trying to combine the `user_id` column  from `friends` table with `id` in `users` table in the `search query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An union is a mathematical operation between sets.
This kind of operations requires the two tables to be COMPATIBLE, which means that they have to have the same columns in number and types.
And it's clearly obvious that you're trying to make an union between a 3 columns SELECT and 1 column SELECT statements (the LEFT JOIN isn't adding other 2 columns as you expect cause the SELECT projects the table after the join is made)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `UNION` for this. You should be using the query this way:

```
SELECT `id`,`firstname`,`lastname`, (
    SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `friends` ON `users`.`id`=`friends`.`user_id`
) AS `UserID` FROM `users` WHERE `firstname` LIKE 
'%ned%' OR `lastname` LIKE '%ned%' 
OR CONCAT(`firstname`," ", `lastname`) LIKE '%ned%' 
OR CONCAT(`lastname`," ", `firstname`) LIKE '%ned%'
```

**Difference**

- `UNION` is for adding as a new row.
- `, () AS Column` is for adding as another column in the same row.

Comment: Sure, explain in your OP. The question. You have an option to edit. We can wait. Reply to the message.

Comment: Looks like you are using a "wrong" schema for friends table. Have you heard of relationships table and six degrees of relationship?

Comment: @IdontReallywolf I really believe this is best: [Facebook Style Friend Request System Database Design](http://www.9lessons.info/2014/03/facebook-style-friend-request-system.html). Lemme know if it doesn't help you. Read the article fully.